# can´t build cordova.jar

Tags: android, cordova, ant, cordova-plugin-proguard

i am currently trying to get into the cross-plattform development for mobile devices with cordova (phonegap).

right now i am *trying* to build the cordova.jar - so i am at the very beginning.

when i run      `android update project -p . -t android-15` in my framework directory  i get the output:

```
E:\eclipse\cordova-android-master\framework>android update project -p . -t android-15
Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
build.xml: Found version-tag: custom. File will not be updated.
Updated file E:\eclipse\cordova-android-master\framework\proguard-project.txt
It seems that there are sub-projects. If you want to update them
please use the --subprojects parameter.
```

Then in the step where i run the command `ant jar` in my framework directory i get the output:

```
Buildfile: E:\eclipse\cordova-android-master\framework\build.xml

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 21
 [checkenv] Installed at E:\eclipse\android-sdk-windows

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: Cordova
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-pre-clean:

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory E:\eclipse\cordova-android-master\framework\bin
   [delete] Deleting directory E:\eclipse\cordova-android-master\framework\gen
[getlibpath] Library dependencies:
[getlibpath] No Libraries
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

build-javascript:

-build-setup:
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for Cordova...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.0.3
[gettarget] API level:        15
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: E:\eclipse\cordova-android-master\framework\bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: E:\eclipse\cordova-android-master\framework\bin\res
    [mkdir] Created dir: E:\eclipse\cordova-android-master\framework\gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: E:\eclipse\cordova-android-master\framework\bin\classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: E:\eclipse\cordova-android-master\framework\bin\dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for Cordova...
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with '${build.target}'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-pre-build:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 53 source files to E:\eclipse\cordova-android-master\framework\bin\classes
    [javac] E:\eclipse\cordova-android-master\framework\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaWebView.java:900: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(boolean)
    [javac]   location: variable settings of type WebSettings
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 1 error
```

does anyone have an idea what i´m doing wrong?

the common-codec-1.6.jar is in the lib folder, just as the readme says.

the android api level 15 is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to build with API level 16 so that you won't get the compilation error. The method WebSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs() was introduced in API level 16.

Comment: Does that means that I will not be able to build Apache Cordova application for my Android 2.3.x phone which has "api level 10"?

Comment: No, that's not what it means. You should always build your Android app with the lastest available SDK and let Android handle the backwards compatibility. Even though you build with API level 16 it will still run on API level 10 devices as long as you don't use API calls introduced after API level 10. The PG project supports API levels 8-17 as of PG 2.3.0 so it will work on any device running those API levels.